# Задать SelectedIndex в ComboBox при привязке данных

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

ComboBox привязан при определенной коллекции данных, которая заполняется полученными из интернета данными после запуска программы. Нужно что бы в ComboBoxе сразу после загрузки данных в коллекцию был выбранным первый элемент коллекции. Напрашивается очевидное решение - после загрузки данных в коллекцию присвоить свойству SelectedIndex значение 0, но в таком случае элемент становится выбранным только после того как пользователь раскрыл и закрыл выпадающий список ComboBoxa. Как сделать так что бы в этом элементе выбранным сразу отображался первый элемент коллекции?

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

XAML

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
// Идем по полученным данным.
foreach (var item in data)
{
    MyCollection.Add(item); // добавляем данные в коллекцию.
}

SelectedItem = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(); // выставляем в качестве выбранного первый элемент
```

Само свойство SelectedItem при этом должно быть INPC,  т.е. должно уметь уведомлять представление об изменении своего состояния.

```
private MyType _selectedItem;
public MyType SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem); // Уведомляем, что состояние свойства изменилось
    }
}
```